# No Extension available when placing a cshtml outside Views Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to Asp.Net MVC and I'm facing a problem when I place a view outside the Views Folder. In my case I really dont need them inside the Views folder because I am working with sitecore which has its own mvc engine and just needs a path to the cshtml file.

However, if I place it inside Views folder, I have the extension Methods available:

[image]

If I create the same File somewhere else, I am missing the extensions:

[image]

What am I missing, and maybe someone could briefly explain what is the magic behind the views folder in that case.

Thanks

Comment: Because your `/Views/Web.config.cs` file specifies the requirements for using the correct assemblies (stik with the conventions unless you have a very good reason not to do so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These extension methods come from `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace.

When the view is placed inside the views folder it gets some default options from `/Views/Web.config` file (including base type, host factory, namespaces etc.).

This is an example Web.config in views folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

If a Razor view is placed in a different folder it won't get this configuration and you'll need to add an `Web.config` in that folder so you can get the intellisense.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, didnt notice the web.config in my views folder.